# Under which conditions is the harmonic function unique that has piecewise constant values on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

$\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$. 
$J_1 = \{e^{i\theta}: \theta \in (0, \pi/2)\}, J_2 = \{e^{i\theta}: \theta \in (\pi/2, \pi)\}, J_3 = \{e^{i\theta}: \theta \in (\pi, 2\pi)\}$

It's not so hard to find a harmonic function $u$ on $\mathbb{D}$ with $u|_{J_1} = 1, u|_{J_2} = 2$, and $u|_{J_3} = 4$

To find such a function, we can transport the problem into the right half plane and take $\tilde u (x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$. Scaling appropriately and adding a constant, we can then use one of many mobius transformations to put it back onto the circle, to get something which is $K$ on an arc of the circle and $0$ everywhere else. Doing it 3 times, we find our function $u$.

But what are the loosest conditions I need so that the solution is unique?

It is necessary that the function be bounded inside the unit disk. But I don't think it's sufficient because we still get many solutions based on our choice of mobius transforms.

One idea is to use maximum principle, but I am not able to make sense of it when the boundary is not continuous.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition for a boundary function to be resolutive (in which case the Perron solution is automatically unique) is that it is $\mu_x$ integrable over the boundary, where $\mu_x$ is the harmonic measure relative to $\Omega$ and $x$. (This is a result from potential theory proven by Brelot. Section 6.4 of *Classical Potential Theory* by Armitage and Gardiner is a modern reference.) For the disk, the harmonic measure relative to $x$ is the surface measure multiplied by the Poisson kernel centered at $x$. Perhaps you can make use of this?

Comment: Cant you just take two solutions, $h_1$ and $h_2$, say, and apply the maximum principle to $h:=h_1-h_2$? Because $h$ is harmonic in $\mathbb D$ and continuous in $\overline{\mathbb D}$, since $h=0$ on $\partial\mathbb D$.

Comment: @Ian This result seems to be above my current level. This question is for a qualification exam in complex analysis.

Comment: @sranthrop How is $h$ defined on the missing boundary points?

Comment: As I said: If $h_1$ and $h_2$ have the same boundary values, then $h=0$ on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are many solutions.
Let $u$ be harmonic and bounded on $\mathbb{D}$ with $u|_{J_1} = 1, u|_{J_2} = 2$, and $u|_{J_3} = 4$. 
Then $v(z)=u(z)+\rm{Re}\frac{1+z }{1-z}$ is harmonic and unbounded on $\mathbb{D}$ with $v|_{J_1} = 1, v|_{J_2} = 2$, and $v|_{J_3} = 4$. Note that $\lim_{x \to 1} v(x)=\infty$.
On the contrary, if $u$ and $v$ are both bounded solutions, then $u=v$ on $\mathbb{D}$.
Proof.  Since $u$ and $v$ are bounded, there is a constant $M>0$ such that $|u-v|<M$.  We define $V(z)$ as follows:
$$
V(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0 }^{2\pi } P_r(\theta -t)h(e^{it}) dt \quad (z=re^{i\theta }),
$$
where $h(e^{it})=M, (t\in [0, \delta ], [\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta , \frac{\pi}{2}+\delta ], [\pi-\delta , \pi+\delta ], [2\pi-\delta , 2\pi])$ and $h(e^{it})=0$ (otherwise), $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel.
Since $u-v-V$ is harmonic and $\limsup_{z \to \partial\mathbb{D} } (u-v-V)\le 0$, we have $u-v-V\le0$ on $\mathbb{D}$ by the maximum principle. Then $u-v\le 0$ because $\lim_{ \delta \to 0} V=0$.
Similarly we have $v-u\le 0$ which concludes $u=v$.

Comment: You could have just defined $V = M$ everywhere. This is the solution to your poisson integral. Also the maximum principal only applies when the function is continuous up the boundary, which it is not in this case.

Comment: Okay I see how you are applying maximum principle but I don't understand the $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}V = 0$ Was $V$ a function of $\delta?$